# What is the form of the Commendatore scene in Don Giovanni?

Tags: musical-forms

The scene has 3 singers with orchestra.  It is not a typical ensemble in that only one voice sings at any one time.  It is rather an exchange of comments, particularly of demands with responses.

I have been thinking about how the Commendatore scene in Act Two of Mozart's Don Giovanni is structured.  My thoughts have settled on a recitativo accompagnato a tre, or an ensemble accompanied recitative.  This section is definitely dramatic, unlike a recitativo secco, and does serve to advance the plot some.  I believe it ends with the entrance of the Furies.  What say ye all?